# Can't trigger "focusin" event for file type inputs in Safari

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, safari, webkit

Safari is not recognising focusin events on file input types. I could listen for a click or value change event but I need this to fire on keyboard-only interaction, somebody tabbing through the form.

I haven't tested this in other browsers besides Safari and Chrome. Is this a know bug? I've seen a lot of issues surrounding Safari input events in general..

```js
const form = document.getElementById("form");
form.addEventListener("focusin", event => {
  $("h2").toggleClass("red");
});
```

```css
input {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 3px solid salmon;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 5px;
}

.red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" id="form">
  <input type="file"><br>
  <input type="text" placeholder="..this is a text field">

  <h2 class="msg">
    I toggle between red and black when you focusin...<br>
    > CHROME: the text input AND the file input<br>
    > SAFARI: only the text input<br>
  </h2>

</form>
```

Not sure if same result with focusout..

Comment: Given that you don't appear to need the event to bubble - which seems to be the main difference between `focusin` and `focus` - can you not use the `focus` event instead?

Comment: Works fine on chrome again, but not safari.. again. Or am doing something wrong as per your suggestion? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XvVBqZ

Comment: I'm assuming you need to delegate event-listeners to the `<form>` element because the `<input>` elements are dynamic?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, can you test your *theory* in my pen?

Comment: also an issue with <button /> elems not triggering `focusin` in Safari/FF :(